# Put range into an array for more efficient loops

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bunch of loops in a function and they loop over an array that I defined as a dynamic range. Below is some pseudocode of what I want to achieve

```
Dim myArray As Range
myArray(x, j) 'So the array loops through each column and then each row in that column
For i = 1 to lastRow
If myArray(x, j).Value = myArray(x, i).Value Then
'Do something
```

I have a bunch of these loops and it's super slow with datasets of 100+ rows. Basically everywhere where I have myArray defined as a Range, I want to change it to a Variant so I can a) loop over the array and b) use the array to check if values are the same instead of checking the range against a range, which is probably the root cause of the performance issues when there are 200 rows * 500 columns

**Edit**

How can I convert a dynamically defined range into an array?

Do I need to do something like this?

```
lastRow = UBound(myArray, 1)
lastColumn = UBound(myArray, 2)
```

And then

```
If myArray(x, j) = myArray(x, i) Then
'Do something
```

Comment: So what is your question? and realize "how can I do this?" is too broad.

Comment: @ScottCraner fair point, give me a second, i will add more code to clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To load a range into an array:

```
Dim RngArr() as Variant
RngArr = WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Value
```

This will create and array that is 4 x 4.

To make the range dynamic

```
Dim RngArr() as Variant
Dim lastrow as Long
Dim lastColumn as Long

lastrow = 10
lastColumn = 10

With WorkSheets("Sheet1")
    RngArr = .Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(lastrow,lastColumn)).Value
End With
```

When loading the array this way the lower bound of both dimensions is 1 and not 0 as it would be otherwise.

To iterate through the array:

```
Dim i as long, j as long
For i = lbound(RngArr, 1) to Ubound(RngArr, 1)
    For j = lbound(RngArr, 2) to Ubound(RngArr, 2)
         'Do something with RngArr(i,j)
    Next j
Next i
```

The second criteria of the lbound and ubound is the dimension.

Comment: How would this work for a dynamic range? So where the rows and columns are both variables

Comment: You would set the range any normal method of setting the range.

Comment: Ok, so in my case I would switch the two loops since i'm iterating columns x rows, right? And then to compare values in cells, i can just do if RngArr(i, j) <> "blank" then ...